# Working with multiple copies of the same module with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I am working on multiple instances of a project in parallel, using IntelliJ Idea (v. 8).

These instances have the same directory structure and are located under different roots. E.g.: c:\projects\projectname_v1  , c:\projects\projectname_v2 , etc...

Currently the IDE is set so that the module is always in the same location (e.g. c:\projects\projectname). If I want to move from one instance to another, I close the IDE and rename the instances.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to just reopen the instance you need from the File | Reopen menu.

Comment: You've got a point there. But I wondered if there was a way to avoid the renaming.

Comment: Settings | Path Variables may be of use here, but only in case your modules are referenced in the project file by the absolute paths. In this case IDEA will replace path you set with a variable in the project file, then you can close the project, replace the path for the variable to another instance location, then open the project. IDEA will replace the variable with the new value and load another instance of your module. But I'd still go with 2 projects side by side.