# How to move hibernate related code to its own 'project' so I can share it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

If I want to be able to re-use my hibernate related code with multiple IntelliJ solutions, what should I do?

Should I move my models (with annotations) and Dao's and service classes to their own module?

How would I then be able to re-use this module/project with other intellij solutions?

I guess they would have to compile down to a seperate .jar right?

Comment: Somewhat related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621964/working-with-multiple-copies-of-the-same-module-with-intellij-idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to configure an IDEA project to point to a module in an external location. So you could configure multiple IDEA projects to point to the same hibernate module. This is a solution for a one-man show, primarily (although see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621964/working-with-multiple-copies-of-the-same-module-with-intellij-idea) about using a variable to make this location configurable).

In order to make this distributable and sharable among multiple developers, you are looking at building a jar out of one module, or if it has no particular meaning to any specific project, making a new project that has the code and produces the jar, which other projects then have as a library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring or Guice for dependency injection. Refactor your dao/services to use generic, so if your children modules don't share the same pojo you can still reuse all your hibernate codes (for dao and services) without any duplications (although you might want to make them abstract, in this case)